For a particular Perm Set, how to write a SOQL to query "Read Access" for all Fields (FLS) for an Object
I'm writing a Batch Job to update FLS across all objects for a particular Permission Set. I can loop the Object and Field describes. From there, it gets confusing.
To simplify, how do I use Apex to set Read Access = true on ADDRESSMEMO here for MyPermissionSet?

With and without @future here, the following hits the 10001 Governor Limit...
public with sharing class FieldPermissionsUtility {
  
    @future
    public static void createFieldPermissions() {
        String INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID = '0PS1Y111000kddfZ';
        Set<String> fieldsWithPermReadTrue = new Set<String>();
        List<FieldPermissions> fieldPermissionsList = new List<FieldPermissions>();
        List<FieldPermissions> fieldPermissionsForInsert = new List<FieldPermissions>();

        fieldPermissionsList = [SELECT Id, Field 
                                FROM FieldPermissions 
                                WHERE ParentID =: INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID 
                                AND PermissionsRead = true];
        
        for (FieldPermissions fp : fieldPermissionsList) {
            fieldsWithPermReadTrue.add(fp.Field);
        }
        
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        for (String objectApiName : gd.keySet()) { // loop all objects
            System.debug('------- objectApiName: ' + objectApiName);
            Schema.SObjectType sobjectType = gd.get(objectApiName);
            System.debug('------- sobjectType: ' + sobjectType);
    
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = sobjectType.getDescribe();
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = objectDescribe.fields.getMap();
    
            for (String fieldApiName : objectFields.keySet()) { // loop all fields per object
                System.debug('>>>> fieldApiName: ' + fieldApiName);
                Schema.SObjectField sobjectField = objectFields.get(fieldApiName);
                String objectDotField = objectApiName + '.' + fieldApiName;
                
                if (!fieldsWithPermReadTrue.contains(objectDotField)) {
                     FieldPermissions newFP = new FieldPermissions();
                     newFP.ParentId = INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID;
                     newFP.SObjectType = objectApiName;
                     newFP.Field = objectDotField;
                     newFP.PermissionsRead = true;
                     fieldPermissionsForInsert.add(newFP);
                }
            }
        }
        Database.insert(fieldPermissionsForInsert, false);
    }
}

... So I tried this, but it also hit the 10001 Governor Limit. Not sure how to put the GlobalDescribe code in a Batch Job.
public with sharing class PermissionSetUpdateBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
  public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
      // need to return something
      return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1');
  }

  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> records){
    FieldPermissionsUtility.createFieldPermissions();
  }

  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    // execute any post-processing operations
  }  
}


Have you read the documentation which describes how you can use related ObjectPermission and FieldPermission records to examine the permissions granted by the perm set?

You can't query for records that don't exist. If PermissionsRead is false for a given field, that record won't exist. This is a performance optimization. Instead, you'll want to iterate over each object, describe the fields for the object, query the FieldPermissions object to see which fields already have permission, then attempt to create a list of field permissions that don't exist. Finally, remember to use Database.insert(records, false);, because some fields can't have their permissions modified. We could try to codify all the rules manually, but it's easier to just let the database do it for us. You can also use ObjectPermissions to restrict the FieldPermissions query to just objects that are being granted permission.

Thank you @sfdcfox, though I'm confused why I need to check which already have permission modified.

please see updates to my original post here. Am I on the right track by considering MDAPI in this fashion?

@RyanMcNeely (a) Recommended so you don't accidentally wipe out any Edit permissions that may exist, and (b) This would be an extremely slow process. Do use FieldPermissions, as you can set many thousands per transaction.

@sfdxfox Global Describe w FieldPermissions is going well.  I just need to figure out how to fit it in a batch job. Please see my original post for my latest code.

@RyanMcNeely Your start method should return a list of object names: public Iterable<String> start(Database.BatchableContext context) { return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().keySet(); }, and from there, you can describe to get the fields for each object. Set the scope to 10 or less to make sure you can accommodate up to 8000 custom fields. You may need to play with it a bit.

orce-app/main/default/classes/PermissionSetUpdateBatch.cls  Class PermissionSetUpdateBatch must implement the method: System.Iterable Database.Batchable.start(Database.BatchableContext) (1:27)

@RyanMcNeely implements Database.BatchableContext<sObject> should be implements Database.BatchableContext<String>.
